# Building Jar in IDEA freezes

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, artifact

I am trying to build a *jar* in *IntelliJ Idea*. (Project structure-Artifacts-Add artifact-Choose module-Create jar). Then I am pressing Build-Build artifacts-Choose my Jar-Build. And then Idea just *reading pom.xml* in background and no jar for me. What could be the solution to this?

Comment: I would get in touch with Serge at JetBrains. He will respond very quickly and knows the product inside-out.

Comment: IDEA/OS versions? Does restarting IDEA help?

Comment: IDEA 11.1.3 Ubuntu 12.04. restartin does not helps

Comment: Do you use encryption for your home folder?

Comment: Nope I got solution. It showed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like [in this instruction](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact). But before I did `File | Invalidate Caches` and it helps.